# Dell Poweredge R710 “System Services update required”

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell, drac, firmware

We just bought a refurbished R710 and upon trying to boot into the system services, it said that system services was disabled, so we booted into the iDRAC6 configuration utility and enabled the system services. Now, when we tried rebooting and going to system services again, it says “system services update required” and as far as I know, the only way to update firmware is with the utilities in the system services. How can we do this? I believe there is a way to do it through an operating system but that’s our last resort, as we don’t have a USB drive to put an os image on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update single component firmware via the iDRAC directly.

The iDRAC6 is old, but it seem to support to do it.

Please see that document on the step by step; [Dell PowerEdge: Update the firmware of Single System Components Remotely Using the iDRAC](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-ca/sln292363/dell-poweredge-update-the-firmware-of-single-system-components-remotely-using-the-idrac?lang=en)

For information the iDRAC8+ it look that way;

```
Go to Overview > iDRAC Settings > Update and Rollback. The Firmware Update page is displayed.

On the Update tab, select Local as the File Location.

Click Browse, select the firmware image file for the required component, and then click Upload.

After the upload is complete, the Update Details section displays each firmware file that is uploaded to iDRAC and its status.
If the firmware image file is valid and was successfully uploaded, the Contents column displays a (+) icon next to the firmware image file name. Expand the name to view the Device Name, Current, and Available firmware version information.

Select the required firmware file and do one of the following:

    For firmware images that do not require a host system reboot, click Install. For example, iDRAC firmware file.

    For firmware images that require a host system reboot, click Install and Reboot or Install Next Reboot.

    To cancel the firmware update, click Cancel.

When you click Install, Install and Reboot, or Install Next Reboot, the message "Updating Job Queue" is displayed.

Click Job Queue to display the Job Queue page, where you can view and manage your pending firmware updates. You can also click OK to refresh the current page and view the status of the firmware update.
```

For the iDRAC6 the official documentation link to that [video](https://youtu.be/2Qh2_ZFTMho);

Comment: Yeah, I'm on idrac6 but I can't access the unified server configurator or anything accessible via system services

Comment: It's working so far. I got that latest idrac6 firmware uploaded and apparently installed so we're just trying to test the new idrac